# What charges/prison time would Jack Black realistically be looking at by the end of School of Rock?

Tags: school-of-rock

Let's say it's the end of the movie. The band has just finished their encore.

The parents and principal have been moved by the performance and realize the positive influence Dewey Finn (Jack Black) has had on the children, so they wouldn't choose to press any charges.

Similarly, Ned Shneebly, the substitute teacher Dewey Finn has been fraudulently impersonating, begins to appreciate his friend despite the bad choices he's made and wouldn't choose to press any charges.

What repercussions is Jack Black facing for his actions throughout the movie?

Comment: This seems to have nothing do with film or TV. You're asking for the legal, real-life repercussions of a situation that happens to have been sketched in a film.

Comment: I’m afraid this question is not very suitable for this site, as it seems to be primarily opinion-based and speculative.

Comment: Lol, it's not opinion-based. Maybe speculative and sure, probably irrelevant but it's not opinion based. But feel free to close this 5 year old question. Keep on fightin' the good fight.

Comment: @Joachim I agree. I started a discussion about this at [meta]: [Should we allow questions about hypothetical legal repercussions a character may face at the end of a movie or TV show episode?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4917/1006) `@CharlesClayton It seems that you acknowledge that your question is speculative and irrelevant (off-topic), which are both reasons to close your question according to the help center on what types of questions are [allowed](/help/on-topic) and [not allowed](/help/dont-ask) here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially the only "crime" Dewey commits is

## False Impersonation

> You falsely personate/impersonate someone else when you falsely represent yourself as another person, for the purpose of deceiving someone.

---

> False personation is what is known as a “wobbler” in California law. This means that it may be charged as either a California misdemeanor or a felony.
>
> If false impersonation is charged as a misdemeanor, it is punishable by a fine of up to ten thousand dollars ($10,000), and/or up to one (1) year in county jail.4
>
> Felony false personation carries a potential fine of up to ten thousand dollars ($10,000), and a potential sentence of sixteen (16) months, two (2) years or three (3) years (which in most cases will be served in county jail under California's realignment program)
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://www.shouselaw.com/false-impersonation.html)</sup>

---

Additionally, he *could* be charged with **fraud** as, presumably, he was receiving a salary under false pretenses but that would be up to the authorities to decide.

As for what punishment he might receive it's impossible to gauge, he might receive leniency after sentencing recommendations...after all he **did a good job** and no-one was *really* harmed...or a judge might decide to throw the book at him.

Comment: He did deprive all those students of the actual lessons they were supposed to learn during that time. His "math lesson" song, where he gives the wrong answer, comes to mind.

Comment: Perhaps but that, in and of itself, is not a crime.

Comment: Of course! I was just thinking about how that might affect his punishment.

Comment: Sure but it seems likely that the entire class and their parent would be character witnesses. I'm not sure there's really any indication that the kids' education was left lacking to any great extent.

Comment: I'm thinking Identity Theft (if Ned presses charges).  And maybe "Endangering The Welfare Of a Child"?  Kidnapping?

Answer (score 1):

In order to be a substitute teacher, you have to pass a criminal background check. The fact that he (presumably) would pass wouldn't change anything, as the argument could be made that IF he had been, say, a convicted sex offender, the kids could have been in danger. He'd likely serve some prison time, and the principal would probably be forced to resign by the school board as there would be some demand for accountability.